# Yum repo on S3: Can I publish repo metadata updates without the full history on a local machine?

Tags: amazon-s3, repository, yum

We have a YUM repository hosted on S3, but the current approach requires maintaining local duplicates of all packages in order to generate the necessary YUM metadata using the "createrepo" command when adding new packages.

Is there a way to generate the YUM metadata files without keeping local copies of all the packages?

I have tried using `createrepo_c` but none of the options provided supports what we want to do.